# Move out of stock products to the end of the catalog product list

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, catalog, product-list, out-of-stock

I need to push out of stock products to the end of catalog list

Please guide me how to solve this problem, or that file to dig

so far I found `Toolbar.php`, and working around it

Comment: Take a look at these articles http://www.ishoni.com/2011/09/magento-out-of-stock-pushed-to-end-of.html, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879978/magento-out-of-stock-products-showing-last-in-the-category-page

Comment: check it out http://ajit-techhub.blogspot.in/2012/01/magento-15-keep-out-of-stock-product.html

Comment: I'm new to magento, so noob question,

/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Collection.php - this file is empty, its ok?

Comment: I don't know the file off hand, but I think you'll want to find where Magento builds the product collection and then add a sort filter like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803495/how-to-sort-a-collection-in-magento

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because too old without an accepted answer

Comment: @SR_Magento This isn't off-topic.  It's old, with no answer - I agree, but it is very much on topic.

Comment: @AlexandrSopkov can you accept the answer. Looks like mageUz's solution is working.

Answer (score 12):

#### Solution 1

This moves out of stock products to the end of the list on page, not all over the pagination:

1.Add event observer:

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <catalog_block_product_list_collection>
            <observers>
                <ssd_test>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>ssd_test/observer</class>
                    <method>catalogBlockProductCollectionBeforeToHtml</method>
                </ssd_test>
            </observers>
        </catalog_block_product_list_collection>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

2.Observer logic:

```
public function catalogBlockProductCollectionBeforeToHtml($observer)
{
    /**
     * @var $products Varien_Data_Collection
     */
    $products         = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
    $soldOuts         = array();
    if ($products instanceof Varien_Data_Collection) {
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            if (!$product->isSaleable()) {
                $products->removeItemByKey($product->getId());
                $soldOuts[] = $product;
            }
        }
        foreach ($soldOuts as $product) {
            $products->addItem($product);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

3.Set "`Display Out of Stock Products`" to "`Yes`" on `System->Configuration->Inventory`.

#### Solution 2

This moves out of stock products to the end of the list within all over the pagination:

config.xml:

```
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_collection_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <review>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>ssd_test/observer</class>
                        <method>catalogProductCollectionLoadBefore</method>
                    </review>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_collection_load_before>
        </events>
    </frontend>
```

Observer.php:

```
    public function catalogProductCollectionLoadBefore($observer)
    {
        $toolbar = Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_list_toolbar');
        if ($toolbar) {
            $products = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();

            $stockId = Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock::DEFAULT_STOCK_ID;
            $websiteId = Mage::app()->getStore($products->getStoreId())->getWebsiteId();

            $products->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                array('_inv' => $products->getResource()->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_status')),
                "_inv.product_id = e.entity_id and _inv.website_id=$websiteId and _inv.stock_id=$stockId",
                array('stock_status')
            );
            $products->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('in_stock', 'IFNULL(_inv.stock_status,0)', array());

            $products->getSelect()->reset('order');
            $products->getSelect()->order('in_stock DESC');

            if ($toolbar->getCurrentOrder()) {
                $products->addAttributeToSort($toolbar->getCurrentOrder(), $toolbar->getCurrentDirection());
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

Set "`Display Out of Stock Products`" to "`Yes`" on `System->Configuration->Inventory`.

Above logics do not affect to your catalog sort/pagination functionality, only moves not salable products to the end.

Comment: Are you sure this will work? It seams it won't affect pagination, but it will move the out of stock products FROM THE CURRENT PAGE at the bottom. So if you go to the next page you might see in stock products after you saw on the previous page some out of stock ones.

Comment: Yes It will move out of stock products to the end of list on every page of pagination

Comment: I think the task here was to move the out of stock products at the end of the list, not the page. So you should see the first N pages with in stock products and once you view an out of stock one, all others that come after that are out of stock.

Comment: Yes, I'll try to give another solution :)

Comment: @Marius, see second solution.

Comment: Solution 2 works like a charm! Thank you very much for this!

Comment: +1 for your answer but what happens when you search item, and that is out of stock product? I am sure searched item shouldn't be at the end.

Comment: Also, when I tried this in EE, threw error, but there is no exact error message, it just says `query was select from .....`, any idea on this?

Comment: @AdarshKhatri maybe your store uses flat tables, I have not tested the solution in EE

Comment: @mageUz, do this solution still works when we sort the results, like - by Name, price etc?

Comment: @mageUz It's not working for configurable product.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented this functionality on my website.

- Copy Collection.php from /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php to /app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/
- Edit Collection.php, around line 1570 find text **$storeId = $this->getStoreId();**
- Add the following lines directly bellow:

  ```
      $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
      array('_inventory_table'=>$this->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_item')),
      "_inventory_table.product_id = e.entity_id",
      array('is_in_stock', 'manage_stock')
  );
  $this->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('on_top',
  '(CASE WHEN (((_inventory_table.use_config_manage_stock = 1) AND (_inventory_table.is_in_stock = 1)) OR  ((_inventory_table.use_config_manage_stock = 0) AND (1 - _inventory_table.manage_stock + _inventory_table.is_in_stock >= 1))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)',
   array());
  $this->getSelect()->order('on_top DESC');
  ```

Flush your cache and your products will now automatically sort the in stock products first and the out of stock products last.

Comment: Please refrain from recommending local core overrides. Would be much better to properly extend the Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection class.

Comment: Perhaps you can add your own answer and show us how to do that?