# Magento 1.9 How to sort product in category page by stocks product

Tags: category, products, sorting, category-attribute, magento1.9.4.4

I want the products to be displayed on the category page, if available
That is, first those that are stocks , then those that are not stocks
I didn't find anything with the title in the attribute
Is there any code?

Comment: do you want to show in stock product first and out of stock in the end ?

Comment: @Pawan Yes in want to show stock product first

Comment: please see my answer and let me know if works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a simple module, say Rave_MoveOutOfStock:

> app/etc/modules/Rave_MoveOutOfStock.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Rave_MoveOutOfStock>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <depends>
         <Mage_Catalog/>
      </depends>
    </Rave_MoveOutOfStock>
  </modules>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Rave/MoveOutOfStock/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Rave_MoveOutOfStock>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </Rave_MoveOutOfStock>
  </modules>
   <global>
    <models>
      <moveoutofstock>
        <class>Rave_MoveOutOfStock_Model</class>
      </moveoutofstock>
    </models>
  </global>
  <frontend>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_collection_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <review>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>Rave_MoveOutOfStock_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>catalogProductCollectionLoadBefore</method>
                    </review>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_collection_load_before>
        </events>
    </frontend>
 </config>
```

> app/code/local/Rave/MoveOutOfStock/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
class Rave_MoveOutOfStock_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{
    public function catalogProductCollectionLoadBefore($observer)
    {
        $toolbar = Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_list_toolbar');
        if ($toolbar) {
            $products = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();

            $stockId = Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock::DEFAULT_STOCK_ID;
            $websiteId = Mage::app()->getStore($products->getStoreId())->getWebsiteId();

            $products->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                array('_inv' => $products->getResource()->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_status')),
                "_inv.product_id = e.entity_id and _inv.website_id=$websiteId and _inv.stock_id=$stockId",
                array('stock_status')
            );
            $products->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('in_stock', 'IFNULL(_inv.stock_status,0)', array());

            $products->getSelect()->reset('order');
            $products->getSelect()->order('in_stock DESC');

            if ($toolbar->getCurrentOrder()) {
                $products->addAttributeToSort($toolbar->getCurrentOrder(), $toolbar->getCurrentDirection());
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Reference: [Move out of stock products to the end of the catalog product list](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17261/move-out-of-stock-products-to-the-end-of-the-catalog-product-list/32950#32950)

Comment: Thank you very much    
I created all the files and folders and cleared the cache     
Then I refreshed the page and it was fine    
Now I have a question    
Doesn't this have a security problem?     
Or doesn't it?

Comment: glad to know it worked. why do you think it has security issue ?

Comment: I only asked one question

Comment: oh, as per my knowledge no security issue with above code

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

please check this solution for out of stock product last display :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879978/magento-out-of-stock-products-showing-last-in-the-category-page

Comment: this not work for my magento